# Define a child class from an abstract parent class, which inherits from an abstract parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance

The situation is (hopefully) clear with the code. We have two (in this example pure abstract, but that isn't necessary) classes. Is this possible to define the class C? What happens to the pointer c_ptr? Do I need to delete it in the class B destructor?

```
class C : public B {
private:
public:
    C();
    ~C();
    int do();
};

class B : public A {
private:
    C *c_ptr;
public:
    B(){
        c_ptr = new C();
    }
    ~B() {
        delete c_ptr;
    }
    virtual int do() = 0;
};

class A {
private:
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    virtual int do() = 0;
};
```

Comment: I suggest to use some basic debugging, e.g. print statements in `ctor`s and `dtor`s. Then instantiate an `A`, a `B` and a `C` one after another, and explain to yourself why each call happens

Comment: Every `C` will have a `C* c_ptr` that will also have another `C*` that will have another `C*`...

Comment: Maybe your intention is to make c_ptr point to the C instance instead of instantiating a new C()?

Comment: non-working code is not very good at explaining stuff. What are you actually trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In short, no, this is not possible.

In your example we have the following constraints:

`B` is child of `A`
`C` is child of `B` is child of `A`

For every super class, there must be an object created as well. So for the instantiation of a `B`, there will be created an `A` first.

The same way for a `C` there will be constructed a `B` which will create an `A` first.

As C++ is a procedural language, datatypes and functions must be known BEFORE using them. However, it is not possible for the compiler to know how to build a `C` before knowing how to build a `B` and vice versa. Therefore it is not possible to do so.

However, this polymorphism structure may be accomplished by using something called Forward Declaration. Basically you tell the compiler that there is some class C which will be specified later on. <kbd>[Example in CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6d5a9n)</kbd>

Comment: You oversaw the problem that, each time C is instantiated, an instance of B is created which again instantiates C, and so on.